# Sharepoint 2007 e 2010 com Office Online 365

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office

Tenho uma demanda em mãos, a empresa que trabalho irá migrar o Office on premise para o online, ou seja, o office será desinstalado da maquina e passaram a usar o online.
Como aqui usamos desde o Sharepoint 2007 ao 2013, gostaria de saber se o 2007 e o 2010 vão conseguir usar os recursos do office 365, para o cotidiano, como abrir arquivos de word, excel, ppt e exportar para planilhas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desinstalar o Office das máquinas dos usuários é desnecessário, a menos que vocês tenham algum problema com licenças.

O Sharepoint 2010 já tinha algum nível de integração com o Office 365, mas como isso é uma solução na nuvem e não de prateleira, qualquer informação que seja válida hoje não necessariamente será válida amanhã. O ideal é alinhar isso com o suporte da Microsoft.

Se vocês partirem para o modelo do Office Online, com certeza o uso cotidiano do Office vai ser tranquilo (desde que vocês tenham máquinas decentes e bastante largura de banda).

A sua preocupação maior será com *event receivers*, *deploy* de sites e a perca de várias funcionalidades que o *on-premises* mas que o *online* não tem. Prevejo que você passará um bom tempo navegando em outro stack, o http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Obrigado Renan, foi de grande ajuda... Vou entrar em contato com a microsoft então, e darei uma olhada no link.
Obrigado mais uma vez